# SNMPGET/WALK Timeout on Printer

Tags: bash, printer, snmp

I have an HP LaserJet CP5225n printer that I am using to test SNMP on our network. I'm new to SNMP so I am having trouble figuring out what's going on here. I'm just trying to return the Device name via SNMP. So I've tried running `SNMPGET` & `SNMPWALK` bash commands and it keeps timing out.

```
--NOTE: IP Address is just for demo purposes. I am using a real IP.
snmpget -c public 0.0.0.0 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 --sysDescr.0
snmpget -t 10 -c public 0.0.0.0 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
snmpget -c public 0.0.0.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.1.3.10.0 --device-name.0
snmpget -t 10 -c public 0.0.0.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.1.3.10.0
```

All of these commands timeout even if i run `snmpwalk` with the same parameters. I have checked the printers web config page. SNMP is enabled. I also had a co-worker perform an snmpwalk with another application and it returned all the desired info. That is also how I know that the OID's are corrected. Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible problems I see are:

1. The IP address shown is `0.0.0.0`. Is that what you're really using? I always use the actual IP address of the target. I didn't see in the man pages where `0.0.0.0` was valid.
2. No version option. Try `-v2c` or `-v1`.

Comment: I am using a real IP. I added the version param and that solved my problem. Thanks.